# Error al sumar los atributos de los objetos

Tags: java, poo

Bien, mi problema es que al tratar de sumar los salarios de los objetos de tipo empleado me  utiliza solamente el último de ellos, lo que levo realizado hasta ahora es lo siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
 App app = new App();
 // App app = new App();
 Empleado[] aa = app.crear_array();

 app.muestraArray(aa);
 app.sumaSalario(aa);
 app.muestraSalario(aa);

 }
// tiene que devolver el array

public static Empleado[] crear_array(){ 
 Empleado[] arrayEmp = new Empleado[2];
 // Rellenamos el array de objetos

 for (int i = 0; i < arrayEmp.length; i++){
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println("Introduzca nombre: ");
   String nombre = sc.next();
   System.out.println("Introduzca apellido: ");
   String apellido = sc.next();
   System.out.println("Introduzca edad: ");
   int edad = sc.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Introduzca salario: ");
   double salario = sc.nextDouble();
   sc.reset();
   arrayEmp[i] = new Empleado(nombre, apellido, edad, salario);
   
   }
 return arrayEmp;
 }

public static double sumaSalario(Empleado[] arrayEmp){

 double suma = 0;
 
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayEmp.length; i++)
   {
   suma = suma + arrayEmp[i].getSalario();
   System.out.println("Suma vale: " + suma);
  
   }
 return suma;
 }

public static void muestraSalario(Empleado[] arrayEmp){
 double sumasalario = sumaSalario(arrayEmp);
 System.out.println("La suma de los salarios es: " + sumasalario + " €");
 }

public static void muestraArray(Empleado[] arrayEmp)
 {
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayEmp.length; i++)
   {
   System.out.println(arrayEmp[i].toString());
   }
 }
}
```

Por otro lado, mi clase empleado es la siguiente:

```
    public class Empleado
  {

  private String nombre, apellido;
  private int edad;
  private static double salario;

  public Empleado(String nombre, String apellido, int edad, double salario)
    {
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellido = apellido;
    this.edad = edad;
    this.salario = salario;
    }
// Por una cuestión de facilitar la lectura, se obvia la lista de 
  // getters y setters no relevantes para el programa

 public double getSalario()
    {
    return salario;
    }

  @Override
  public String toString()
    {
    return "Nombre: " + this.nombre + " Apellido: " + this.apellido + " Edad: " + this.edad + " Salario: " + this.salario;
    }

  }
```

La salida que obtengo es la siguiente:

```
Introduzca nombre: Juan 
Introduzca apellido: Perez 
Introduzca edad: 30 
Introduzca salario: 1000 

Introduzca nombre: Eva 
Introduzca apellido: Flores 
Introduzca edad: 31 
Introduzca salario: 2000

Nombre: Juan Apellido: Perez Edad: 30 Salario: 2000.0
Nombre: Eva Apellido: Flores Edad: 31 Salario: 2000.0
La suma de los salarios es: 4000.0 €
```

Como se puede comprobar arriba, a pesar de haberle indicado al programa que el salario de Juan son 1000, el salario de ambos objetos tiene el valor del segundo o último elemento añadido.

Muchas gracias de antemano, saludos!

Comment: Crucial: _¿depuraste tu código?_

Comment: Sí, el problema es que le cambia el valor a salario sin que haya ningún set de por medio... De hecho, en el último párrafo de la pregunta se ven los sout informando del valor de suma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ten cuidado al momento de declarar tus variables

```
 private static double salario;
```

no dede ser static, ese es tu error.Al ser static solo toma un solo valor osea el ultimo que le des.

Comment: Justamente era eso lo que pasaba, error de novato, lección aprendida.
Muchas gracias!!!